# Extending Func to accept array parameter in C#

Tags: c#, linq, delegates

I have been using Func to create

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(block, paramValues).Compile();
```

Where block is Expression.Block that creates the required execution plan. paramValues is an array of Expression.Parameter values:

```
 var paramValues = epDef.Value.Parameters.Select(p => Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), p.Name))
            .ToArray();
```

I am trying to modify this to accept an array, so that I can use Func when I have more than 16 input parameters:

```
Expression.Lambda<Func<object[], object>>(block, paramValues).Compile();
```

However this gives me the following error:

```
Incorrect number of parameters supplied for lambda declaration
```

Can anyone help me with using Func to accept more than 16 parameters in this case? either using an array as input or by creating a custom delegate

@MethodMan:

I tried to implement the solution in that question, but I am getting the same error. From what I understood, changing the Expression.Parameter from `typeof(object)` to `typeof(object[])` should have worked in my case, but I get the same error

EDIT:

Here's the modified version of what I tried from the linked version:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] argas)
        {
            Type[] types = new Type[] { typeof(object[]) };

            var constructorInfo = typeof(Program).GetConstructor(types);
            var parameters = types.Select((t, i) => Expression.Parameter(t, "p" + i)).ToArray();
            var someType1Exp = Expression.New(constructorInfo, parameters);
            var inner = Expression.Lambda(someType1Exp, parameters);

            var args = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]), "args");
            var body = Expression.Invoke(inner,
                parameters.Select((p, i) => Expression.Convert(Expression.ArrayIndex(args, Expression.Constant(i)), p.Type)).ToArray());
            var outer = Expression.Lambda<Func<object[], object>>(body, args);
            var func = outer.Compile();

            object[] values = { 1, 123.45F, "abc" };
            object obj = func(values);
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        //public Program() { }
        public Program(object[] values) { Console.WriteLine(values.ToString()); }

    }
```

I get the following error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Object[]'.'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use lambda expression parameter in "sub" expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135625/how-to-use-lambda-expression-parameter-in-sub-expression)

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is you changed your lambda to take a single array argument, `object[]` but you are still passing in multiple arguments (`paramValues`). You need to pass in a single value, the `Array`. You will also need to modify your expression body to expect an array.

Consider before you had the equivalent of

```
(a,b,c,d) => new Program(a, b, c, d)
```

Now you want

```
(object[] a) => new Program((type0)a[0], (type1)a[1], (type2)a[2], (type3)a[3])
```

So you need to modify your code to reference the elements of the parameter array instead of the parameters directly:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] argas)
        {
            var constructorInfo = typeof(Program).GetConstructors()[0];
            var types = constructorInfo.GetParameters().Select(p => p.ParameterType);
            var parm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]), "args");
            var parameters = types.Select((t, i) => Expression.Convert(Expression.ArrayIndex(parm, Expression.Constant(i)), t)).ToArray();
            var someType1Exp = Expression.New(constructorInfo, parameters);
            var outer = Expression.Lambda<Func<object[], object>>(someType1Exp, parm);
            var func = outer.Compile();

            object[] values = { 1, 123.45F, "abc" };
            object obj = func(values);
            Console.WriteLine(obj);
            Console.WriteLine("test");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        //public Program() { }
        public Program(int val1, float val2, string val3) { 
            Console.WriteLine(val1);
            Console.WriteLine(val2);
            Console.WriteLine(val3);
        }
    }
```

If you want to pass the `object[]` to the constructor, as in

```
(object[] args) => new Program(args)
```

you can just do that directly (sorry for formatting, copied from my LINQPad):

```
public class Program  {
void Main() {
    var constructorInfo = typeof(Program).GetConstructors()[0];
    var parm = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object[]), "args");
    var someType1Exp = Expression.New(constructorInfo, parm);
    var outer = Expression.Lambda<Func<object[], object>>(someType1Exp, parm);
    var func = outer.Compile();

    object[] values = { 1, 123.45F, "abc" };
    object obj = func(values);
    Console.WriteLine(obj);
    Console.WriteLine("test");
}

// Define other methods and classes here
    public Program(object[] parms) {
        Console.WriteLine(parms.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, but I want my constructor to be `public Program(object[] vals)` so that the delegate can be called with any number of parameters. since I am sending in `values` to the delegate, which is an object array, I don't understand why accepting an object array in constructor doesn't work.

Comment: So you want something like `(object[] a) => new Program(a)`? I added another example.